# Team Web Access Test Case Details

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

One of my users noticed something weird with the TFS 2012 Team Web Access.  She enters the Test Case work item using Test Manager.

One of the steps is multi-lined.
Saved fine on TM.

[image: MTM]

However, everyone sees the HTML encoding on Team Web Access. 
[image]

Is there a fix for this or is this the default behaviour?

Comment: That looks a lot like TFS 2010 Team Web Access, are you sure it's 2012?

Comment: You are right, Dave! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  The QA tester still has 2010 client for some reasons and launches the team site from there. I emailed her the URL for the 2012 version and that works great.

Comment: Dave, how do I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: I've added it an answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the TFS 2010 web access. You should use the 2012 version and this won't be a problem any more.